# Align text and icon in center of div

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, primeng

I create a rating scale has N  with fixed width.
Each rate has got a value which is shown inside of the correspective **div** and a description.

My problem is that the description and the relative icon are not align in center under the **div** but starts from the left.

```
  <div class="card card-accent-primary">
    <div class="card-header text-left">
      Rating values
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="col-12 mt-2 mb-1 p-buttonset valore-rating-display justify-content-center">
        <div *ngFor="let scala of scalaRating; let i=index" style="width: 5rem">
          <div>
            <button pButton type="button" label="{{scala.valoreRating}}" class="p-button-outlined cursor-default"
                    [class.rounded-left]="i == 0" [class.rounded-right]="i == (scalaRating.length - 1)"
                    style="background-color: {{scala.codColoreValRating}}; color: black; width: 5rem">
            </button>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="rating == scala.valoreRating" class="position-relative">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-up font-weight-bold font-xxlarge"></i>
            <div class="position-absolute" style="word-wrap: break-word; left: -1rem">{{scala.descrizioneValRating}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I want the icon and description positioned in center like in the image(I marked with red color the desire position):
[image]

Here there is the example code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a3akxa?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <div *ngFor="let scala of scalaRating; let i=index" class="wrapper">
      <button ...></button>
      <ng-container *ngIf="rating == scala.valoreRating" >
        <i class="..."></i>
        <div style="word-wrap: break-word;">{{scala.descrizioneValRating}}
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```

an unique class: wrapper (and forget position:absolute, margin-left....:)

```
.wrapper{
  width:5rem;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  align-items:center;
}
```

See how the `<i>` and the `<div>{{scala.descriptineValRatting}}</div>` has the same "parent" that the `<button>`

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wgdpb9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: that's it a fantastic solution.! You're right I have to add a unique class wrapper. Just a little explanation, why flex-direction column?

Comment: I want the three "divs" go from top to down, not from left to rigth see, e.g. [this link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flex-direction)

Comment: ook thanks a lot.! I will read and study it

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to app.component.css :

```
.fa-caret-up {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Enjoy! :)

A little explanation:

- Didn't want to add more classes
- Display flex is fantastic for centering content
- If you wanna learn more about display: flex, try this: https://flexbox.buildwithreact.com

[image]

Comment: But the text it’s not aligned yet

Comment: Oh damn, I thought it was only the icon, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using flex to accomplish this like
https://codepen.io/jayu/pen/gObPVgj

```
<div class="demo-solution demo-solution--flexbox">
   <img width="100" height="50" src="http://placehold.it/100x50" alt="" />
   <span>Alignment using flexbox</span>
</div>

.demo-problem, .demo-solution {
  font-size: 3em;
}

.demo-solution--flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin:auto;
  img {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: margin 300ms;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution without flex layout:

1. icon.
   add `text-align: center;` to icon's parent div (the position-relative one)
2. description
   add `left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, 0);` to the description div to implement the center aligning.
   such as: `<div _ngcontent-ghu-c0="" class="position-absolute" style="word-wrap: break-word;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, 0);position: absolute;">F - RISCHIO MEDIO</div>`.
   Make sure the position-relative class has `position:relative;` style.

```css
.box {
  text-align:center;
}
h3 {
  padding-top: 60px; 
  margin:0;
}
.line {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color: #f1f1f1; 
  position: relative;
}
.fCell {
  text-align:center;
}
.desc {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.doCenter {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  color: red;
}
```

```html
        <div class="box">
            <h3>Original:</h3>
            <div class="line">
                <div class="fCell">F</div>
                <div class="desc">hello world!</div>
            </div>
            <h3>use left/transform to center long size text:</h3>
            <div class="line">
                <div class="fCell">F</div>
                <div class="desc doCenter">left/transform to center</div>
            </div>
            <h3>use left/transform to center small size text:</h3>
            <div class="line">
                <div class="fCell">F</div>
                <div class="desc doCenter">f</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: The risk for the text description is if  I apply the left 50% for shorter text, it will not align center but it will align in the left. That’s not my purpose

Comment: @travis_911 shorter description text works too, it's NOT based on the length of text. I added  some example codes for you.